# Changing the DOM elements charset of my addon

Tags: encoding, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Spanish "Firefox for Android" addon which allows adding divs and show [doorhangers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Mobile/API/NativeWindow/doorhanger) on certain pages. But every message I put into them appears with a wrong encoding.

For example, instead of showing "Esta página" shows "Esta  p**Â!**gina".

Does anyone know how to change the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: save the bootstrap file with encoding Western IDO 8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

The doorhangers (just like any other JavaScript API) work with Unicode - you call that API with JavaScript strings that contain Unicode data, there can be only one correct way to display it. If the encoding you see is incorrect then it only means that the strings you pass in already have wrong data.

In your case it seems that a UTF-8-encoded string was interpreted as ISO-8859-1. If this string came from a JavaScript file, you might want to consider the  [documentation on JavaScript file encodings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/International_characters_in_XUL_JavaScript):

> When the JavaScript file is loaded from a chrome:// URL, a Byte Order
>   Mark is used to determine the character encoding of the
>   script.

So you may want to save your JavaScript file with a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Alternatively you can define that string as `"Esta p\xe1gina"` to eliminate the encoding ambiguity. Of course, this is only a temporary solution for testing - your final extension should have [all localizable strings in `.properties` and `.dtd` files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Localizing_an_extension), these files are assumed to have UTF-8 encoding by default.

If you get the data from the server, you might want to ensure that the encoding is set correctly in the `Content-Type` header.